# Wifi hotspot working but cannot ssh pi via ethernet connected to router

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, ethernet, access-point

I got wifi hotspot access point working I followed steps as shown on this page:
https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/#comment-17588

Now I can connect to wifi hotspot created by raspberry pi but I cannot access raspberry pi via ssh. I checked router admin page and in connected devices it shows

```
titan   192.168.1.187 192.168.1.122 xy:yz:eb:8a:47:fa   Ethernet    3
```

now it shows 2 ip addresses and the mac address is different than the previous one.
Earlier it shows 1 ip address.

Comment: have you enabled ssh?

Comment: yes, everything was working until I setup wifi hotspot access point on my pi

Comment: so I gave up using as wifi hotspot because the static IP I gave to `eth0` was getting assigned to the `br0` interface, I think that is what was restricting me to ssh, but even when I assign different static IP address for `br0` and `eth0` i was still not able to ssh . one strange thing I noticed I probably don't know even when I was setting wifi hotspot, the raspberry pi Acesspoint I connected from phone showed me home router as router and it's DHCP was assigned ip address to my phone rather than the raspberry pi

Comment: You may try [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). It does not use additional helpers and may be less confusing.

Comment: made backup of configs now I am going to start doing that.